# C/C++ expected primary-expression before "else"

Tags: c++

can someone help me? im just starting programming on C/C++ (im using DevC++)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int X;
    int Y;
    int R;
    cout << "FUNCION POTENCIA";
    cout << "Ingrese primero la base y luego el exponente";
    cin >> X, Y;
    if (Y = 1) {
        R = X;
    };
    //if
    else() {
        do
            while (Y > 0) {
                R = X * X;
                Y--;
            }; //do while
    }; //else   cout<< R;
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
} //main
```

Comment: `else()` is wrong, it should be `else`. Please read a few tutorials about the subject before asking questions here. And welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: remove ; before else, also there should not be any parenthesis with else (else() is wrong)

Comment: Unforutunately you have syntax errors all over the place. If you fix that one you will just get the next one. Probably better if you go back and read a beginner's tutorial. Using stackoverflow as a line by line syntax checker isn't going to work well :-)

Comment: C/C++ isn't a language. Judging by your code it seems you're learning C++.

Answer (score 2):

You have five errors:

1. `cin >> X, Y;` doesn't read user input to both `X` and `Y`. It's actually two separate statements: `cin >> X;` and `Y;`. The first one reads user input to `X`, the second one evaluates the current value of `Y` and doesn't do anything to it. To read user input to both variables: `cin >> X >> Y;`.
2. `if (Y = 1)` will *assign* `1` to `Y`. You want to check for **equality** with `==`: `if (Y == 1)` i.e. *"if `Y` is equal to `1`"*.
3. Don't put semicolons after `if`, `else`, and `while` blocks. They're redundant and cause errors like this. Put semicolons only after *statements*.
4. Don't put `()` after `else`.
5. A *do-while* loop is `do { ... } while (...);` not `do while (...) { ... }`, whereas a *while* loop is simply `while (...) { ... }`.

Here's the correct version:

```
...
cin >> X >> Y; // 1.

if (Y == 1) { // 2.
    R = X;
} // 3.
else { // 4.
    while (Y > 0) { // 5.
        R = X * X;
        Y--;
    }

    // or if you want a do-while:
    do {
        R = X * X;
        Y--;
    } while (Y > 0); // semicolon here!
}
```

In conclusion, pick a [book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to learn the language properly, so you can stop guessing what the right syntax is.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have a semicolon after your if statement. 
Correct if statement form is:

```
if(expression)
{
     // If Code
}
else
{
     // Else code
}
```

Comment: Remove the () after the else, and the pretty much any semicolon that immediately follows a close bracket.  I could be forgetting something but I don't think }; is ever correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (Y = 1) {
        R = X;
 };
```

Remove the last ";" here.